# Why there is index.php and .htaccess into all Prestashop subfolder?

Tags: php, .htaccess, prestashop

In pratically each sub folder of Prestashop, you can found an **`index.php`** file that contains :

```
<?php       
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

header("Location: ../");
exit;
```

and an **`.htaccess`** one that contains :

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

I understand that .htaccess one prevent the user to access that folder but I'm more curious about what they do with index.php, what does it do exactly ?

Comment: It just redirects to one folder level up, and adds some instructions on how this response should not be cached … It’s basically a fallback to prevent listing of directory contents, if the .htaccess should not be taken into account for some reason (like a server having parsing those turned off.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .htaccess add a security by removing access to the current directory with the "Deny from all" rule.

The index.php is in every folder to prevent direct access to folders. For example if you type in browser www.myshopurl.com/modules, you will be redirected back to home page since you're not suppose to access or view the contents of this folder.